# Could not connect: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

Tags: php, mysql, centos

When i connect my database by a php script it shows

```
Could not connect: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

the username and password is right.

something of the `my.cnf`

```
[client]
#password       = your_password
port            = 3306
socket          = /data/mysql/mysql.sock

# Here follows entries for some specific programs

# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
port            = 3306
socket          = /data/mysql/mysql.sock
skip-external-locking
```

ps: i change it to `socket = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock`  the php script  still says "/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock"?. then run

```
  mysqladmin -u root -p status
```

it shows

```
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)'
Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' exists!




service mysqld restart


mysqld: unrecognized service
```

Comment: The error suggests you're trying to use `/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock` whereas your configuration suggests the socket is actually located at `/data/mysql/mysql.sock`...

Comment: i change it to   socket          = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock  the errors is still there

Comment: On a Debian system the command to restart the MySQL server is `service mysql restart`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q: Does your my.conf still says "/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock"?

Q: Does the directory "/var/lib/mysql" exist?

Q: Does your mysql user (or better, mysql group) have writer permission?

If so, please try re-starting mysql and see what happens.

ADDENDUM:

One other thing to try is to *create* a mysql.sock and explicitly *give* it permissions:

```
cd /var/lib
mkdir mysql
touch mysql/mysql.sock
chown -R mysql:mysql mysql
```

Comment: i am sorry. i am a newbie of linux. i don't know how to check your 3Q. could you tell me how to check them. many thanks

Comment: 1) sudo bash # become "root", 2) ls -ld /var/lib/mysql # check if directory exists, and the directory permissions

Comment: ls: /var/lib/mysql: No such file or directory

Comment: what's this chown -R mysql:mysql mysql line meaning. thank you